# What's the difference between "*" and "+" in lm() in R?

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

I would like to preface this post that I'm an absolute noob with R and have a somewhat basic grasp of statistics. I want to apologize if I mix the terminology up (and that I most definitely need to do more reading).

I'm currently looking at a dataset with 17 variables, 1 is the dependent variable and the remaining 16 are the independent variables. I need to select the "best" linear model between these variables.

So here's what I'm working with:

```
MA1 <- step(lm(
  as.formula(paste(colnames(NLCD)[1], "~",
  paste(colnames(NLCD)[c(2:17)], collapse = "*")
  )), data = NLCD
))
```

So `MA1` is a model and `NLCD` is the name of the dataset. I'm confused as to whether use `"*"` or `"+"` for the stepwise regression. When I run the model with the `"*"`, RStudio freezes for a while then spits out a bunch of `NA` with lots of the header names and `:`. I thought using `"*"` would be best as it saves me from having to write the code manually, but I don't really know what's its purpose is. Ideally, I would have to run probably up to a hundred models, shuffling between combinations, hoping for the best, then selecting the model with the lowest AIC value.

Initially, I was thinking of just using p-values instead -- where I would take out the independent variable with the lowest p-value until I only have one independent variable left, then selecting the model with the lowest AIC value. I don't know if I could do it better by using `"*"` instead.

Comment: Using `*` will add an interaction term. So `~a*b` is the same as `~a + b + a:b`. But if you have many variable and try to create all possible interactions, the number of terms you create will quickly grow. You need to have a lot of data to estimate a bunch of interaction terms.

Comment: The best way to learn about this is to ask R with `?formula` where you will learn that "The * operator denotes factor crossing: a*b interpreted as a+b+a:b." Sixteen independent variables make for a lot of interactions.